# Magento 2 - Debug, backtrace

Tags: magento2

hace poco hice la migración de M1 a M2 y estoy teniendo un problema que no consigo resolver.

Me gustaría que me ayudarais a hacer un debug más completo.

Uso el tema Infortis Ultimo que añade una extensión MegaMenu que se gestiona desde las edición de categorías.

No me está salvando ninguna de las opciones de este menú excepto una o dos irrelevantes.

Me gustaría saber que está sucediendo cuando envío el POST para tratar de solucionar el problema pero no consigo hacer un debug que me muestre errores sql o php concretos.

Comment: A quién haya votado negativo la pregunta, muchas gracias. Pero, ¿como hago un print_r de un controlador magento 2 del backend para saber que datos y dónde los está transportando el array?

Answer (score 0):

He trabajado con dicho menú y en ocasiones tiene algunos problemas dependiendo de la cantidad de parámetros que se envíen o por JavaScript.

Para hacer un debug rápido, puedes hacer obtener los datos del POST en el controlador con la siguiente línea, e imprimir dicha información:

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost();
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!, no creo que sea por la cantidad de elementos pero lo tendré en cuenta.
Gracias por la ayuda para obtener la el debug desde el controlador.
Voy a probar a ver si consigo que funcione :)